Add a shell command to dired mode
I want to add a command to dired-mode, which executes a shell command on the highlighted file. For example, from Bash, I can run qvm-copy {FILENAME}. I would like to replicate this behavior, but from within a dired buffer, executing on the highlighted file. How can I accomplish this?

dired-do-shell-command, usually bound to !?

This seems close. I'm trying to bind this to the "C" key within a hydra. So, for example, would that be ("C" dired-do-shell-command qvm-copy)? Or do I need some different elisp?

Sorry: I don't know the hydra syntax but whatever it is, you want to execute (dired-do-shell-command "qvm-copy").

This does not quite seem to work for me. Even without hydra, if I just create a function, (defun qcopy () (interactive) (dired-do-shell-command "qvm-copy")), this runs, but returns the output: "Shell command succeeded with no output". This is not anticipated. Whereas, if I execute ! from dired, then type "qvm-copy" then ENTER, it opens a pop-up, as I expected. I am trying to replicate this behavior, but with a keybind (so I don't have to keep typing "qvm-copy" ENTER).

Try (dired-do-shell-command "qvm-copy ?") and see the doc string of dired-do-shell-command for more details.

Describe in more detail what you want your command to do, e.g. the interaction. Otherwise, as others have mentioned, you just have it invoke dired-do-shell-command with the args you want.

I suggest you check out dwim-shell-command package. It is a practical solution.
